# 「関数へ渡す引数」が少ない場合の挙動

Tags: プログラミング言語

**PHP 7.1 以降で、(ユーザ定義)関数へ渡す引数が少ない場合エラーになることを知り驚きました**

---

**Q1.他のプログラミング言語では、関数に渡す引数が少ない場合、一般的にはどういう挙動になるのでしょうか？**
・これに関して、実装の流行りとかそういうのはあるのでしょうか？

**Q2.「言語に組み込みの関数」と「ユーザ定義関数」の挙動は一般的には異なるのでしょうか？**

---

**質問背景**
・「関数へ渡す引数が少ないことを認めない言語」の方が多い、もしくはそれが普通かどうか、知りたいと思ったので

Comment: 「3個の仮引数をとる関数があったとき、2個以下の実引数で関数を呼び出す」という意味ですか？

Comment: 内部関数というのは、言語に組み込みの関数やライブラリ関数のことですか？

Comment: @yohjp はい。「3個の仮引数をとる関数があったとき、2個以下の実引数で関数を呼び出す」という意味です

Comment: @nekketsuuu はい。内部関数は「言語に組み込みの関数」の意味で質問しました。分かりにくいので修正しました

Comment: 参考までに教えていただきたいのですが、PHPのこの挙動を知る前にre9さんが前提としていた挙動は、どのプログラミング言語のどのようなものだったのでしょうか？

Comment: 事前にイメージしていた言語は特にありません。質問背景としては、引数の挙動そのものよりも、引数の挙動を途中で変更しなければいけない程のことなのか、(私が)判断する材料にしたいと思い質問しました

Comment: ちなみに、RFC( https://wiki.php.net/rfc/too_few_args )での主張は「少ない引数で呼び出されることを考慮していない関数の誤動作を引き起こすし、考慮してるならデフォルト引数で代用できる」といったもののようですが、その効果のほどやマイナーバージョンで（互換性のない）変更をする必要性については開発者ML( https://marc.ttias.be/php-internals/2016-06/ )でも議論になったようですね。結局39対11で採用されたわけですが。

Comment: なるほど。経緯は公開されているのですね

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A1. エラーになる言語もありますが、許容する言語もあります

C 言語では通常はエラーになりコンパイルが通りません。

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int main() {
  add(0);  // ←エラー
  return 0;
}
```

しかし、可変長引数という仕組みを使うと許容されます。

```
int add(int a, ...) { // ... は２つ目以降を受け取ることを表す
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, a);
  int x = a + va_arg(ap, int);
  va_end(ap);
  return x
}

int main() {
  add(0);  // 実行されますが返ってくる値は不定です
  return 0;
}
```

C++ ではデフォルト引数というものを使うと許容されます。

```
int add(int a, int b = 0) { // 指定しなかった場合の引数を指定できます
  return a + b;
}

int main() {
  add(0);  // b は 0 として扱われるので 0 が返ってきます
  return 0;
}
```

Javascript では実行されます。

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

add(0); // 動作します。b は undefined という指示されていないという意味の値になり、 NaN を返します
```

デフォルト引数と可変長引数どちらも言語特有ではなく多くの言語にある仕組みです。

> 「関数へ渡す引数が少ないことを認めない言語」の方が多い、もしくはそれが普通

JavaScript のようなどんな数の引数でも認める言語は少ないと思いますが、多くの言語はデフォルト引数と可変長引数があるので、そういう意味では引数が少ないことを認める言語のほうが多いと思います。

### A2. 関数がどのように定義してあるかによります

PHP にもデフォルト引数、可変長引数があるので、それを使っている関数の場合は引数を少なくすることができます。

Comment: C 言語 が厳格なだけで、「デフォルト引数と可変長引数」はプログラミング言語的には一般的な考え方なのですね。また、PHP については「デフォルト引数、可変長引数」は今回の質問とは関係ないのですね。勘違いしていたことに気が付きました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 3):

話題に出ていない言語かつ少ない引数を受け取れるものだけをピックアップしました。

---

Haskellでは、引数が少ないと渡されたところだけ部分適用された関数を返します。

```
add a b = a + b
x = add 1 -- 引数を一つ取る関数が返る
y = x 2   -- 3が返る
main = print y -- 3を表示
```

全てがカリー化されている他の言語や、カリー化している関数はすべてこのような動作になるでしょう。

---

Rubyでは、通常のメソッドは引数の数が合わないとエラーですが、Procはあわなくてもnilが補充して渡されてエラーになりません。しかし、似たような形のラムダ式はエラーになります。

```
# nilを+するとエラーになるため、エラーにならないようにしています。
def add(a, b)
  a.to_i + b.to_i
end
add_p = proc { |a, b| a.to_i + b.to_i }
add_l = -> (a, b) { a.to_i + b.to_i }
add(0) # ArgumentError 引数の数が合わないのでエラー
add_p.call(0) # 0, nil がわたされ、0が返る
add_l.call(0) # ArgumentError 引数の数が合わないのでエラー
```

Answer (score 2):

@ryohey さんの回答にちょっと補足いたします。

C言語の関数の呼び出し時に、引数はパラメーターより少なくでも、コンパイルできる場合もあります。例えば

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = foo(2); // 引数が1つ
    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

int foo(int p, int q) // パラメーターが２つ
{
    return p + q;
}
```

gcc 4.9 でコンパイルすると、`-Wimplicit-function-declaration` をつけなければ、警告もエラーもありません。

当然、これは正確な仕上げ方ではありません。こうして出来たプログラムを実行すると、未定義の動作となりますので、いかにも危険です。

これはC言語の歴史的な問題です。以前、宣言機能がつけられていなかったので、コンパイラーが定義されていない関数の呼び出しを見ると、「この関数が任意の数の `int` 型のパラメーターを必要とされ、戻り型も `int` である」っと判定します。ゆえに、引数とパラメーターの数が違っても、コンパイルする時にエラーがありません。

Comment: この例、`int foo(int, int)`をプロトタイプ宣言するとエラーになるんですね。面白いです。

Answer (score 2):

補足です。

関数に[多重定義、オーバーロード](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A%E9%87%8D%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9)という概念を持つ言語があります。（C++、C#、Javaなど）
これは引数の異なる同名の関数を定義することを認めるもので、関数呼び出しの際に引数からどのバージョンを呼び出すかを判別します。

```
// ２引数バージョン
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

// ３引数バージョン
int add(int a, int b, int c){
    return a + b + c;
}

int main(){
    int sum1 = add(1, 2);     // ２引数バージョンを呼び出す
    int sum2 = add(1, 2, 3);  // ３引数バージョンを呼び出す
    int sum3 = add(1);        // コンパイルエラー
}
```

最後の`add(1)`に関しては、２引数バージョン・３引数バージョンいずれにも引数が適合しないため、呼び出すことができずコンパイルエラーとなります。

このことは裏返せば、**関数に渡す引数が少ないことを許容する言語**は関数オーバーロードを実現できないことになります。

Comment: 最後の1文は早すぎる一般化だと思います。どういう意味で「関数に渡す引数が少ないことを許容する」かによって話が異なりますし、極端な仕様を持つ言語がコーナーケースになりえます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、イメージがわかないので具体例を挙げていただけませんか？ 一般的なプログラミング言語に関する質問、それに対するデフォルト引数と可変長引数の回答、それに対する補足の話題なのですが。

Comment: たとえばJavaでは可変長引数の仕組みと関数オーバーロードが（適当な意味で）同時に実現できます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、**引数が少ない**とは「『3個の仮引数をとる関数があったとき、2個以下の実引数で関数を呼び出す』という意味」だそうです。Javaは**引数が少ない**呼び出しを認める言語なのですか？

Comment: 他の方の回答で可変長引数を「引数が少ない」の意味で取り扱っているものがあったため、「引数が少ない」の意味による、と書きました。もしJavaの例がsayuriさんの想定外なのでしたら、たとえばJavaScriptにおける関数オーバーロード（に相当する実装手法）なら想定内になるのではないでしょうか。[ryoheyさんの回答](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/33213/19110)やEcmaScriptの仕様に書いてあるように、JavaScriptにおいては関数呼び出しの規約がかなり柔軟に決められています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、可変長引数は任意の引数を認めるものでは？ 例えばC言語の`printf`は1個以上の引数を認めます。これに対し0個の引数で呼び出すならば「足りない」と言えるでしょうが1個の引数で呼び出す場合を「足りない」と言うのでしょうか？ またJavaScriptは関数オーバーロードを認めているのでしょうか？ 百歩譲って関数オーバーロードに模したオブジェクトについてですが、例えば3個の引数を要求する関数オーバーロードに模したオブジェクトに対して2個の引数で呼び出した場合、実行時エラーにならないのでしょうか？

Comment: JavaScriptに関してですが、少なくとも呼び出しに関して実行時エラーにはなりません。オーバーロードに関しては[この投稿](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)に寄せられているいくつかの回答のような実装を想定しています。JavaScriptでは仕様上「オーバーロード」という言葉は出てきませんが、そもそも関数呼び出しの規約が他の有名な静的型付け言語とそれなりに離れている気がします。より詳しい仕様に関しましてはStandard ECMA-262の9.2 "ECMAScript Function Objects" などをご覧ください。

Comment: sayuriさんはどのような例が「引数が少ない」呼び出しだと考えていらっしゃるのでしょうか……？　それでは他の例として、C++においてデフォルト引数の仕組みと関数オーバーロードが（型による幾らかの制約を除いて）同時に実装できている、というのだとどうでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、リンク先は質問文から既に「fake function overloading」と言っていて[回答](http://stackoverflow.com/a/457589/4315484)も引数を一つのオブジェクトにまとめていてオーバーロードでも何でもないですが。[これ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8338720/4315484)や[これ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21875788/4315484)は明示的にエラーにしていますし[これ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17137284/4315484)も引数が多いと`TypeError`を引き起こします。エラーにならない回答もありますが処理を端折っているだけでは？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55312/discussion-between-nekketsuuu-and-sayuri)しましょう。